# Creating a tree-shakable angular library with a single import module

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, webpack

### Context

I am creating a library with 2 ways of initialization:

1. Automatic - I download some stuff for you asynchronously, then initialize.
2. Manual - You already downloaded the stuff before, then I initialize the library immediately (sync).

I have successfully implemented tree-shakable libraries in the past. What we would normally do, is separate the code into two modules, and let the app developer choose which one to import, thus allowing tree-shaking the other part. Similarly to this:

```js
import { LibraryAsyncModule } from 'my-library'; //  Or LibrarySyncModule

@NgModule({
    imports: [LibraryAsyncModule] //  Or LibrarySyncModule
})
export class AppModule { }
```

### What I want to accomplish ✔

To reduce the learning curve of using my library, I'm trying to design is a single imported module which includes the relevant module and allows tree shaking the other. The following diagram shows the desired structure.

[image]

### What I want to avoid

I could create factory providers that will detect the config passed to `forRoot()` and load the corresponding module at **runtime**. However, importing the modules at runtime turns initialization to async, and will also prevent angular from bundling the used module with the app.

I need a **build time** solution. My prototypes show that simply including both sync and async modules in the core module result in both being bundled.
How would that single module look like? Any ideas / suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Your approach should work, but you will need to enable it.

Since Tree-shaking works only with `es6` modules you need to publish your lib with it & specify `module` property in your `package.json`.

```
// package.json
{
  ...
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "module": "dist/es/index.js", // <- this file should contain es modules not commonjs
  ...
}
```

This setup will tell bundlers (webpack in your case) to use the `es` modules export and allow them to enable tree-shaking feature.

I recommend for package devs to use [`tsdx`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsdx) cli tool which does this automatically and supports many other features such as TypeScript support etc.

```
npx tsdx create mylib
```

Comment: Hi @felixmosh, thanks for the reply. Could you provide an example, or a link please? I don't quite understand how to implement what you're suggesting.

Comment: just try my suggestion lib (tsdx) it will help you to understand it.

Comment: tsdx looks interesting, however I'm looking for a different kind of solution. More specifically, I'm trying to avoid incorporating yet another tool in my workflow. We all have enough of those, don't we? 

Comment: This is a dev tool for building a libs, no need to encorparate yet another tool, this will define all you need, it supports TS out of the box

Comment: _"This is a dev tool for building a libs"_
I understand. I simply can't really believe this will end with a simple `npm install tsdx` command...

Comment: From my experience tsdx make it super simple to develop a lib, just run this at some side folder, `npx tsdx create mylib` you will see all the configs that you need to make in order to get tree-shakable lib